# Trying to convert a for loop to SIMD in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, simd

For a game i'm trying to make faster, i have a part of code that makes sure tanks evade eachother, by pushing them away from eachother with a force.

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < (MAXP1 + MAXP2); i++ )
{
    if (game->m_Tank[i] == this) continue;
    float2 d = pos - game->m_Tank[i]->pos;      
    float dlsq = (d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y);
    if (dlsq < 64) force += normalize(d) * 2.0f;

    else if (dlsq < 256) force += normalize(d) * 0.4f;

}
```

Now i'm trying to do 4 tanks at a time using SIMD, so i have

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (MAXP1 + MAXP2) / 4; i++)
{
    union {
        __m128 valuesx4;
        float valuesx[4];
    };
    union {
        __m128 valuesy4;
        float valuesy[4];
    };
    __m128 dx4 = _mm_set_ps((pos - game->m_Tank[i*4]->pos).x, (pos - game->m_Tank[i*4+1]->pos).x, (pos - game->m_Tank[i*4+2]->pos).x, (pos - game->m_Tank[i*4+3]->pos).x);
    __m128 dy4 = _mm_set_ps((pos - game->m_Tank[i*4]->pos).y, (pos - game->m_Tank[i*4+1]->pos).y, (pos - game->m_Tank[i*4+2]->pos).y, (pos - game->m_Tank[i*4+3]->pos).y);
    __m128 dlsq4 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(dx4, dx4), _mm_mul_ps(dy4, dy4));
    __m128 sixtyfour4 = _mm_set_ps1(64.0f);
    __m128 twofiftysix4 = _mm_set_ps1(256.0f);
    __m128 mask0 = _mm_cmpeq_ps(dlsq4,_mm_set_ps1(0.f));
    __m128 adjdlsq4 = _mm_add_ps(dlsq4, _mm_and_ps(mask0, _mm_set_ps1(300.f)));
    __m128 mask1 = _mm_cmplt_ps(adjdlsq4, sixtyfour4);
    __m128 mask2 = _mm_and_ps(_mm_cmplt_ps(adjdlsq4, twofiftysix4), _mm_cmpge_ps(adjdlsq4,sixtyfour4));
    __m128 multiplier4 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_and_ps(mask1, _mm_set_ps1(2.0f)), _mm_and_ps(mask2, _mm_set_ps1(0.4f)));
    __m128 rsqrt4 = _mm_rsqrt_ps(adjdlsq4);
    __m128 values4 = _mm_mul_ps(rsqrt4, multiplier4);
    valuesx4 = _mm_mul_ps(values4, dx4);
    valuesy4 = _mm_mul_ps(values4, dy4);

    force += (valuesx[0], valuesy[0]);
    force += (valuesx[1], valuesy[1]);
    force += (valuesx[2], valuesy[2]);
    force += (valuesx[3], valuesy[3]);
}
```

I adjust the dlsq to account for the case where the checked Tank is the current Tank. For some reason however, in contrast to the normal way where the tanks gather around the target and stay roughly in a filled circle around the target, in the SIMD version, the tanks start following a sloped line and intersecting with eachother. They all move on a line with direction (1,-1) from the target. Does anyone see where it goes wrong?

Comment: For a loop like this, the compiler should do a pretty good job of vectorizing the code itself (assuming proper optimization flags are set). Do you have evidence that it isn't? Also: you assume that `MAXP1 + MAXP2` is divisible by 4 - is that guaranteed?

Comment: Divisibility by 4 is guarantueed. I have no direct evidence that the compiler isn't optimizing this very well, except for that this part of the code still takes a significant portion of the time. I was hoping to compare the normal code to my explicit SIMD to see if it gains anything, but then i want to make sure it works properly of course. Even if it doesn't give a performance boost, the SIMD practice is always welcome.

Comment: The gather at the front and unpack at the end are going to be a performance problem:  `__m128 dx4 = _mm_set_ps(... 4 separate things from an array of structs )` will compile to multiple loads and shuffles.  The `force += (valuesx[0], valuesy[0]);` inside the inner loop is also horrible.  Accumulate two vectors of X and Y forces in the loop, and do the horizontal stuff at the end of the loop.

Comment: Can you store your tank data in a struct of arrays, with separate packed x and y arrays?  See also https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ for more tips about designing your program to be SIMD-friendly, linked from the [sse tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info).